# Code coverage of a c++ dll which is tested through c# MSTest

Tags: c#, c++, code-coverage, mstest

I'm using a C# MSTest project to test a C++ dll. I want to know how much code in the c++ dll is covered with my MSTests. Is there any way to get code coverage of a C++ dll which is tested through a C# MSTest project?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it compiled properly to expose the code coverage information?

Comment: MSTest project is compiled without errors. I did not understand the meaning of compiling properly to expose the code coverage information.

Comment: To enable code coverage, you need to compile it into the C++ library.